# In ASP, C#, and VB.Net how to retrieve current line number

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic

Does ASP, C#, VB.NET have a way to retrieve what line its on in code as its processing commands?

Example

```
1 <%
2 response.write("Your on line " & retreiveCurrentLineNumber)
3 %>
```

Output: Your on line 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var line = new StackFrame(0, true).GetFileLineNumber();
```

Note there are several caveats to this.

1. You will need to make sure the source file and PDB are reachable.
2. This will get you the current line of the *method* you are in, not exactly where you are.
3. The Jit may perform optimizations that result in incorrect information, such as a method being inlined.

For VB.NET it's the same thing:

```
Dim line As Integer = New StackFrame(0, True).GetFileLineNumber()
```

As far as Classic ASP goes - I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: @RetroCoder I don't believe that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

While vcsjones answer may be exactly what you're looking for, for the purposes of debugging/troubleshooting VB.NET you may want to take a look at the Erl property of the Err object. It returns an integer indicating the line number of the last executed statement - and by line number, that means a numeric label, not the physical line number of the source file.

Peppering one's code with line numbers at critical points is helpful at troubleshooting the unexpected exceptions, and one doesn't need the source file and PDB to make Erl work.